# What does Google mean with "Google APIs"? Is an App Engine endpoint (e.g. xxx.appspot.com) a Google API?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-cloud-functions

I have a couple of running Cloud functions that fetch data from an external API and then post the received data into an internal API which is running on Google App Engine. I've come up with this approach because the external API has a rate limit that I sometimes need to bypass.

In order to calculate the monthly cost of this setup I was looking at the Google Docs and saw this:

> Outbound data to other Google APIs in the same region is free, as is inbound data. Where the Google API you are using is global (i.e. not region-specific), it is considered to be the same region.

**My question: What does Google mean with "Google APIs"? Is an App Engine endpoint (e.g. xxx.appspot.com) a Google API?**

Comment: An App Engine application endpoint is not a Google API. When your endpoint is called or when your app calls another app endpoint such as Cloud Functions, those items are billable subject to the billing details. The Google APIs quote that you provided is for the APIs written by Google that manages the service and is not related to features your application provides publically or to your other applications/functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google APIs generally refer to the [APIs and services provided as part of Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/apis), as well as other Google services such as SMTP provided by Gmail and recaptcha.